# Set array to have a maximum of 21 elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, and I don't know how may elements there are in the array. It could be 1, it could be 500, but I need the maximum amount to elements to be 21.

I know I can check the length using `count()`, but how do I chop the rest off if it is too long? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SplFixedArray` it a good way to manage fixed size array .....

```
   $array = new SplFixedArray(21);
```

Example

```
   $array =  SplFixedArray::fromArray($array);
   $array->setSize(21);
```

[See PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfixedarray.construct.php)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
if(count($array) > 21){
    $subarray = array_slice($array, 0, 21);
}
```

Explanation:

```
array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
```

array_slice() returns the sequence of elements from the array array as specified by the offset and length parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is $arr then:

```
$subArray = array_slice($arr,0,21);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_slice to chop off the exceeding portion.

```
if(count($array) > 21){
    $array = array_slice($array, 0, 21);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) by specifying the offset as 0, and length as 21.

```
 if(count($your_array) > 21){
  $new_array = array_slice($your_array, 0, 21);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove the elements beyond what you need